# Can't figure out why I get this NullPointerException on my EditText

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, datepickerdialog

I'm using Android's DatePicker to select a certain date from the calendar. The problem is I don't manage to show the date I select from the calendar in my EditText.

This would be my `DatePickerFragment`:

```java
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

 private EditText a;
 private String date;

 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

  a.findViewById(R.id.in_date);
  date = "";
  date = Integer.toString(day) + "/" + Integer.toString(month) + "/" + Integer.toString(year);
  a.setText(date);

  // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
  return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
 }
}
```

and this is the xml of the EditText I'm using:

```java
< EditText
android: id = "@+id/in_date"
android: layout_width = "175dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: hint = "@string/choose_date"
android: importantForAutofill = "no"
android: inputType = "date|text"
android: keyboardNavigationCluster = "false" / >
```

Every time I get `NullPointerException` when trying to use `.setText(date)` on the EditText variable `a`. Isn't this the way it should be initialized?

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing the variable `a` which means it is `null`. You're getting the `NullPointer` because in the background, it is doing `(null).setText(date);`

`EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.in_date);`